# Adding filled 2-D plot/object (created by plt.fill) into 3-D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a 2-D plot that has a custom green polygon over a red square:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

corners_x = [10/3, 10/3, 0, 1.30435]
corners_y = [5/6, 5/3, 5, 1.08695]

NonFeasibleSet = plt.fill([0, 5, 5, 0], [0, 0, 5, 5], "mistyrose")
feasibleSet = plt.fill(corners_x, corners_y, "palegreen")
plt.show()
```

[image: 2-D shape/plot]

I want to add this plot/object on the XY plane, with the lower left corner of the image at (0,0,0) of the following 3D plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
plt.xlim([0,5])  
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.show()
```

[image: 3-D Plot]

I'm fine if I have to recreate the red square like I did below. However, I was wondering if there was an easier way to recreate the green polygon for 3D plotting.

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

searchSpace = Rectangle((0, 0), 5,5, color="mistyrose", alpha=0.45)
ax.add_patch(searchSpace)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(searchSpace, z=0, zdir="z")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work for ya:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

corners_x = [10/3, 10/3, 0, 1.30435]
corners_y = [5/6, 5/3, 5, 1.08695]
corners_z = [0, 0, 0, 0]

corners = [list(zip(corners_x, corners_y, corners_z))]
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(corners))

plt.xlim([0,5])  
plt.ylim([0,5])
plt.show()
```